# JS functions to add days to the HTML select box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append my select box, so it shows days from 1 to 31 but when i reload the page it appears like a selectbox and the days are looped 3 times.

```js
function selectDays()
{
    var min = 1,
              max = 31,
              select = document.getElementById('selectDay1');

              for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
              var opt = document.createElement('option');
              opt.value = i;
              opt.innerHTML = i;
              select.appendChild(opt);
              }
}
```

```html
              <div class="col-sm-4" id="day">
              <select class="form-control" id="selectDay1" onclick="selectDays()">
                <option selected>Day</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Everytime you click your select, it will add 31 days. May call selectDays *onload* ...

Comment: Also, you can simplify the 3 lines of creating an option to the following: `var opt = new Option(i, i);`

Answer (score 1):

Only add once, after the DOM is loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', selectDays);

function selectDays()
{
    var min = 1,
              max = 31,
              select = document.getElementById('selectDay1');

              for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
              var opt = document.createElement('option');
              opt.value = i;
              opt.innerHTML = i;
              select.appendChild(opt);
              }
}
```

```html
              <div class="col-sm-4" id="day">
              <select class="form-control" id="selectDay1">
                <option selected>Day</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!